# Is solely using Bootstrap Studio for frontend development considered a bad practice?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, frontend

I have little to no experience with frontend development. But I do know PHP.

I am currently developing a simple site based on the Laravel framework by designing the pages using Bootstrap Studio. Is this a bad thing to do for production websites and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code generated by Bootstrap Studio should work just fine for production but you'll likely need to become somewhat familiar with HTML and CSS (plus Bootstrap) and possibly JavaScript anyways to get anything created in Bootstrap Studio to work within blade templates (if you're rendering data from a database or submitting any forms).

I'd recommend using Bootstrap Studio for inspiration and generating a reference but there's not really a way around learning HTML and CSS (possibly JavaScript too).

Check out:

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

And then go back to the Bootstrap documentation:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction

You can do it!